# Reputation Report was brutally murdered

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-audit

OK, perhaps not brutally...

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation no longer displays any actual information:

[image]

Comment: neither does meta for that matter...

Comment: Nor the rest of the network.

Comment: Is that red stuff supposed to be blood? It doesn't look very bloody, or very blood-red.

Comment: @animuson: Can you do a better job?  How's http://i.stack.imgur.com/ahgrO.png?

Comment: @animuson, the title mentions "brutally murdered"...it's clearly strawberry jam.

Comment: It's back [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) (at 2012.1.26.701) but not yet [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) (at 2012.1.25.695).

Comment: @SLaks: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NlVD5.jpg ?

Comment: That's much better.

Comment: In the site index, the title of this post combined with the status tag generates a chuckle :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be available again in the next deploy (very soon).

Comment: It doesn't look fixed to me

Comment: @SLaks "coming soon"

Comment: How long do your deployments take?

Comment: @SLaks the "precious" has been restored

Comment: That's better.  I see that my reputation was recalced yesterday.